# Did Gru Make more minions?

Tags: minions, minions-movie

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39659/where-did-the-minions-come-from) answers the question of where the minions came from.

However, it contradicts what is said the the short "Orientation Day"

> We're more than co workers we're family, after all we are all made from the same strand of mutated DNA

Is there any other evidence that Gru made more minions?

Comment: How does this indicate that gru made them? That could also still point to the minions origin as in the minions movie so not really seeing how you came to the conclusion that gru made them?

Comment: There was originally going to be a gag in the first movie that the minions were actually genetically modified corn (just look at them!), but it was cut, and their origins were later changed.

Comment: there is still a poster in the girls bedroom in the original that is basically a schematic / internals of a minion, also indicating that the original intent is that were created, not natural beings as later shown in the Minions movie